# Can I make asynchronous requests with Ruby's Typhoeus?

Tags: ruby, typhoeus

I am using Typhoeus and would like to make a single request without blocking for the response. Later on, I might check the response, or I might not. The point is I don't want the code execution to wait for the response.

Is there a way to do this built-in to Typhoeus?

Otherwise I guess I have to use threads and do it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a [thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html):

```
response = nil

request_thread = Thread.new {
  # Set up the request object here
  response = request.response
}
```

From there you can check `response == nil` to see if the request has been made yet, and you can call `request_thread.join` to block until the thread is done executing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the 'unirest' gem for Ruby.

As far as I am aware, Typhoeus blocks on the 'hydra.run' call

With Unirest, it does not block on the get / post / put / etc call, but continues to run. If you want, you can store the 'object' in a hash or an array with an identifier to retrieve later, like so:

```
identifier_requests['id'] = Unirest.post(url,headers: headers, parameters: param, auth: auth)
```

Then to block, or retrieve responses, use one of the calls on the response object:

```
response_code = (identifier_requests['id']).code
response.body
```

http://unirest.io/ruby.html

Answer (score 0):

Typhoeus has non-blocking calls built-in. From their docs:

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new("www.example.com", followlocation: true)

request.on_complete do |response|
  if response.success?
    # hell yeah
  elsif response.timed_out?
    # aw hell no
    log("got a time out")
  elsif response.code == 0
    # Could not get an http response, something's wrong.
    log(response.return_message)
  else
    # Received a non-successful http response.
    log("HTTP request failed: " + response.code.to_s)
  end
end

request.run
```

This is from their docs at https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus